# Cannot navigate out of route with a parameter with React Router in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am having trouble when using my navigation bar to move away from a route that is not accessible from it.

Here is my navbar:

[image]

When the use clicks on `Search` they are presented with a table of charities listed in my country. The route to the `Search` page is:

`<Route path="search" component={SearchContainer} />`

From the table you would click on a particular charity to be taken to it's page. The route for this is:

`<Route path="charity/:registeredCharityNumber" component={CharityPageContainer} />`

The problem is that once viewing a Charity, clicking on any item in the navigation navigation bar results in an error in the web console:

[image]

The nav bar works perfectly before but after you visit the charity page route you see this error. The only way to fix this is to do a browser reload.
Clicking on the error in the browser debug view highlights (4th line) this section of code:

[image]

This is what my Router looks like:

```
export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePageContainer} />
      <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route path="search" component={SearchContainer} />
      <Route path="contact" component={ContactPage} />
      <Route path="thankyou" component={ThankYou} />
      <Route path="charity/:registeredCharityNumber" component={CharityPageContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Here is the CharityPageContainer:

```
export default createContainer(( { params: { registeredCharityNumber }} ) => {

  const charNum = parseInt(registeredCharityNumber);
  const subscriptionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('current.charity', charNum);
  console.log('CHARITY OBJECT ',currentCharity(charNum).fetch()[0]);
  const loading = !subscriptionHandle.ready();
  return {
    subscriptionHandle,
    loading,
    charity: currentCharity(charNum).fetch()[0]
  };
}, CharityPage);
```

And this is the important section of my navbar component:

```
<Link activeClassName="active" className="item" to="/">Home</Link>
<Link activeClassName="active" className="item" to="/about">About</Link>
<Link activeClassName="active" className="item" to="/search">Search</Link>
<Link activeClassName="active" className="item" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
```

**Using**
"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-router": "^2.6.0",

Comment: Please paste code from CharityPageContainer.

Comment: @Ula I have pasted as per your request.